# General tab missing

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have just switched over to using Xcode 5. 
I have gone to change the name of my application with some other settings which I need to change, However when I have gone to do this I noticed my "General" tab is missing. Does any one know why this may have happened.

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

See up in the left hand corner of your screenshot the blue icon? You have your project file selected and are viewing the project's global settings, which don't have a "General" tab.

Click either the triangle in the box up there or the lower blue icon with "template" and select a build target.

Answer (score 122):

Just a quick update how to do it in Xcode 8:

[image: get the general tab]

Comment: For UI difficulties, GIFs are the best.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing your project's settings. You want to see your target's settings.

In the bar containing 'Info' and 'Build Settings' click on the project icon on the left and select your main target from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

For me, General tab re-appeared when I did shift-command-Y which closed the debug window on the bottom.

The open debug window caused the tab bar with "General" to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the application is on the Utilities file inspector for the project. With your project selected, press Cmd-opt-1 (or in the menus, View->Utilities->Show File inspector)