# Xcode error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ios10, code-signing

I have Xcode 8 installed on OS X El Capitan.

I get this error:

> Signing for "target" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>
> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: You need to go to the General tab and select a Team.

Comment: This should (surprise) happen to people the have been using "Run" (simulator) successfully, but not when they want to "Archive". Can you confirm the command that triggered this error?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

### With Xcode-8.1 & iOS-10.1

1. Add your Apple ID in Xcode `Preferences` > `Accounts` > `Add Apple ID`:

[image: Step 1]

2. Enable signing to Automatically && Select Team that you have created before:

[image: Step 2]

3. Change the Bundle Identifier:

[image: Step 3]

4. Code Signing to iOS Developer:

[image: Step 4]

5. Provision profile to Automatic:

[image: Step 5]

You can now run your project on a device!

Comment: Where is the enable automatic sigin? That I don't see in xcode 8

Comment: Select Target  and then select General. You can see Automatic signin :)

Comment: It is not explained where many of these options are beyond the first step which is why this answer is not useful for me. Also where is Target? Can you please give step-by-steps?

Comment: Configuring Xcode to just run your project s***s on so many levels. There is absolutely no need to be that complicated.

Comment: For those confused how to get to the signing page, you double click the top file in your file explorer, that opens the project settings where you can select the bundle name and signing

Comment: you guys need to know that have people who come here without ANY base, help them (me including) with a step by step please

Comment: Note: in more recent versions of XCode, that option for automatically manage signing would be in the "Signing & Capabilities" tab. –

Comment: Where is Target?

Answer (score 461):

To add developer account to Xcode:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma)
2. Go to `Accounts` tab
3. Follow the screen shot below to enable development team:

[image: Step 3]

At least in some cases, it might also be necessary to trust your Developer Profile on the mobile device. If you see the "Untrusted Developer" error dialog on the mobile device, see [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206143/ios-untrusted-developer-error-when-testing-app/206144#206144).

Comment: you not need developer account for testing. apple id is enough with latest `xcode`. You can test your app in devices by your apple id only!

Comment: I did tried many times by adding and deleting the accounts in xcode but still not able to get through the above error. Automatic signing is enabled and some other team is selected instead of actual APP ID.

Comment: For those who can't find `general` tab. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407439/general-tab-missing

Comment: What does "You can set it from `general`" mean.  Who's the general, where does he live, and what army?  Need more context please.

Comment: Image is not available anymore. Please upadte

Comment: Cheers for using technology from 1987 to present your answer

Comment: I'd love an updated screenshot for this. 2016 was a minute ago.

Answer (score 85):

In case you are still having this problem, click on the Tests and select a team for them too.

Comment: and sub-project also!

Comment: where can I click on "Tests" ?

Comment: I already had the team selected long ago, but now that I started making the tests, they have this problem. Neither clicking on the top-level test "folders" or the test code files themselves brings up anyplace where I could select the development team for them. This is Xcode 10.2.

Comment: On Xcode 11.3, under the project file there are tabs for General, Signing, etc. To the left of those nav buttons there should be your project's name in a dropdown. That is the target, click the dropdown to select a different target, e.g., the tests and from there you can select the signing.

Answer (score 29):

To run your app on a real device, you need to have an Apple ID, and have registered your device with that ID. That is why you are getting this error.

Here's how you do it.

1. Go to the project Navigator. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> if you can't find it.
2. Click the project target dropdown and pick Target. 
   [image]
3. Click on the Team dropdown and pick add an account.
   [image]
4. Sign in with your Apple ID that is linked to your developer account, or just your Apple if you don't have a dev account.
5. If you haven't registered your device with that account yet, a button will appear, something like 'Register device'. Click that and Apple will register the device and do the certificates and code signing. (Oh my unicorns certificates and signing is so much easier than it used to be)
   [image]

Pick your physical device and hit run and it should load onto your device without error.

Comment: Great job answering this question, and I love the screenshots. Thanks! Cool that you don't have to pay $99 to run any more.

Answer (score 25):

Well, after I did all those things I still got the errors so I closed Xcode and opened it up again and then it worked.

Comment: Haha, don't know why, but that solved it for me, too!

Comment: same here. So follow the steps up then close Xcode and reopen it again

Comment: Same here. Follow the steps on the approved answer then if it doesn't work close xCode then open the workspace again then the job is done. LOL

Comment: A disappointingly robust solution to all Xcode code signing problems for the past few years :/

Answer (score 17):

#### Xcode 11.4

Click on:

1. Your project
2. Signing & Capabilities
3. Select your Team.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you add the team on both Debug and Release tabs.

[image]

Comment: Was going to add this answer but saw yours first. Felt dumb after wasting 10 minutes.

Answer (score 11):

For those that are going to come here after me, if it's Xcode 11 and iOS 13 then your layout might look a little different than what you see in the main answer to this question.

Firstly, do this as it was mentioned in the answer: Add your Apple ID in Xcode Preferences > Accounts > Add Apple ID.

Then click on the project name which is located in the left panel. Then you'll get a window of settings. Then look for "Signing & Capabilities" and that's where you'll be able to see "Team" and select your name as the option.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Recently had the issue on **Xcode 11** beta 2:

1. Select your project on the left side panel
2. Find the "**Signing & Capabilities**" tab for your target

*If your target doesn't have the "Signing & Capabilities" tab (in my case only the test target had it), open the build settings for your project and click "All" instead of "Basic"/"Customised". Find signing under the settings and make sure you've got a Development team set up.*

3. Repeat the same step for your test target if needed

Answer (score 8):

If you need to disable the team for now, as you don't have a development account, just change the target at the top menu to iPhone instead of a generic iOS device or real device.

Answer (score 6):

Select team in the general settings of the target

Comment: This is actually the solution that resolved it for me

Comment: To get to this general settings, select the dropdown at the top and change it to your device

Answer (score 5):

For those using `Ionic` and receiving this error - you need to open your `$project_dir/platform/ios/$project_name.xcodeproj` - then follow the steps listed in the "answer"

Comment: @jonesy827 there is, search here for subject `With Xcode-8.1 & iOS-10.1`

Comment: Yep, someone must have updated it. Definitely was not when I made the comment :)

Thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 4):

Select the development team in both project and target. For the rest, set to "automatic" and then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error on my React Native project, weirdly enough I thought I was **NOT** editing the correct .xcodeproj file! I went into my project directory './*appname*/ios' and opened the project file and edited my team name into the project and it started working.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. As a relatively new Xcode user, I do feel compelled to mention that this is the type of change best done in Xcode GUI, when possible, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the bar where you have file, edit, view etc
Go on view -> Navigators -> Show Project Navigator -> Click on team -> Select yours.

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

selecting a team worked for me. but I had to do it for all of the imported libraries even though I didn't own them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the iOS development Target from `12.1` to `12` fix the issue for me as I don't have a dev team configured.

Answer (score 0):

in Xcode13: select your project -> in Navigatr bar you will see TARGETS -> Click on the project name below the TARGETS -> you will see the Signing& Capabilities

Comment: How does this add information or clarity to what has already been shared?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me just change in the build settings to release from debug
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWRCV.png)