# How to test NativeScript app on real iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript and I just made my first app. My app requires testing on a real iPhone; however, I don't know how to test it on a real iPhone and not the simulator. I tried looking at the appbuilder docs but I can't figure out how to just test it on an iPhone. I tried to use `tns run ios` while I had an iPhone plugged in but I get this:

```
=== BUILD TARGET LOKale OF PROJECT LOKale WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Signing for "LOKale" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65
# run ios
```

I have no idea why I can't just run it on an iPhone. Can anyone tell me how to test it on a real iPhone or what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538

Comment: @YuchenZhongThese look useful, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in the link provided in the comments, to test on real device you will need to provide **development team id**.

Here are the steps to do it in NativeScript application:

- Open ***app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig***
- Uncomment (or add) `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = YOUR_TEAM_ID;`
- Place your team id and rebuild your application

**Update:** You can also use

```
tns run ios --provision
```

to see the available provision profiles and build the app with

```
tns run ios --provision <my-provision-profile>
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: what do I use for my TEAM_ID? Is it something like a UUID or just a name?

Comment: In the same file (build.xcconfig) above the team id line there is a link that that leaeds fot the Apple article for the development ID https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html

Comment: Basicvally here is the place where you can find your team id https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1#/membership

Comment: Yep - fromthere go to Memebership and see your Team ID