# Working on iOS 9.3 simulator gives this error in xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have to test my app in iPhone 4S in Xcode 8.1 so I installed 9.3 simulator in xcode but when i build my app I got this error.

[image]

Comment: and whats the error ???

Comment: whats the error , specify the eror?

Comment: @Purushothaman i have updated my question, image of error.

Comment: You need to required to select your developer team for code signing !!! Refer [this so post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod/39524311#39524311)

Comment: @Lion thanx for your response i have done that but got same error