# XCode 8: "Automatically manage signing" option is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

While building my iOS project with XCode 8, I have the following error :

```
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
```

I found many answers and most of them are saying that checking the `Automatically manage signing` option in the project's settings page can solve the problem.

But, the `Automatically manage signing` option is missing. How can I make it appear ?

Comment: have you configure your apple id in accounts in xcode?

Comment: Yes. How could it be related to the problem as the issue comes from the project's settings template ?

Comment: if you haven't configured or added apple id or apple developer id in your accounts then automatically code signing option will not appear!

Comment: In fact, it's configured.

Comment: Also, you have to select the target rather than the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Automatically manage signing option : Availabe under project-> Targets-> General-> Signing section

Answer (score 0):

You have sign in to and apple id in xcode `Xcode -> Preferences... -> Account -> +` after that the option to `Automatically manage signing` should appear.