# Signing for "appname" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

I can't run my app because there are two issues:

*Signing for "Locker" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.*

And

*Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'*

Now, on my project page I have everything configured for the signing and the development team:

[image]

And yet I still have the two issues. Can tou help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod)

Comment: Try disabling `Automatically manage signing` and then re-enabling it.

Comment: @I'L'l his is not a duplicate because that post is outdated. It suggests Automatically manage signing yet the option is not where the answer describes it.