# xcode is giving error on running application on iphone device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I choose my iphone in device and run my application in xcode .It is giving following error.

Signing for "sneaker" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'
How i can get rid of these error and run my xcode application in iphone ?

Comment: possible duplicate, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46261291/3266248

Comment: Obvious dup of something. Question is, what have you configured so far?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, sign up for a developer account at developer.apple.com and then goto Xcode > Preferences and add your account details.

You need to have a developer license to run on a physical device. You can run on the simulator even without a license.

Once you have a license, if you are still having issues refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic) for further information

Answer (score -1):

You can **debug and run your application** into inbuilt **simulators**

And to run application on iOS devices, you need to **sign up and buy Apple Developer Account** with membership

[Membership details](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

Then **add apple account into Xcode**

[Add apple account in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html)

and here is the link **for running application on iOS devices**

[Step to run in iOS device](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: This is not correct. Running on devices no longer requires a paid developer account.

Comment: But i found that we have to add iOS device UDID, to run in device, and for that we need to buy paid account

Comment: See the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod . Joshua Dance's answer contains a good explanation on the process . Currently, all that is needed is a free Apple ID.

Comment: I will try, thnx for updating me