# Requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting the following error:

> Code Signing Error: Signing for "AppsMobileCompany" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.

[image: Please help me with it. I don't know what to do. For real, I am kinda noob. Helpe me lol]

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=requires+a+development+team.+Select+a+development+team+in+the+project+editor) before posting.

Comment: but i did and it did nor work.

Comment: @Wanderley Silva your question helped me a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/xcode-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios)

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT: Apple has since updated Xcode and as a result, picking your team is now in the Signing & Capabilities tab.**

You need to select your team in the general tab. If you have not set up a team you can set it up at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)

[image]

Comment: how do I do this by script. My cordova project creates a new xcodeproject every build and breaks my ci pipeline.

Comment: Note: in more recent versions of XCode, that option would be in the "Signing & Capabilities" tab.