# Xcode error: Signing for ... requires a development team

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ios13, xcode11

I am trying to test my app on my iPhone 8. Since I do not have an Apple Developer Account, I have followed this tutorial: https://ionicframework.com/blog/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/

Although the above tutorial is for Xcode 8 (I have Xcode 11), it worked until the second-to-last step. I had already added my Apple ID and created my certificate (e.g. **NT Larry (Personal Team)** with Role of **User**). I went to Signing and Capabilities >> Signing >> Team (dropdown) and in the dropdown menu I chose my certificate (**NT Larry (Personal Team)**). Then, I clicked Run. The following error appeared:

> Signing for "ntlarry_project StickerPackExtension" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor

However, as detailed above, I have already taken the action requested (adding the development team, in this case my Personal Team) in the above error. What should I do to resolve this error?

The answers in other questions like this one ( [Xcode error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/xcode-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios)) and this one ([Requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890569/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor)) have not helped me since I took the same approach as they did. Is it because the new versions of Xcode require a Apple Developer Membership in order to do this kind of testing?

More details:

I am making this app for **iPhone 8**, with **iOS 13.1**. I am using **Xcode 11**.

If you would like more information, please ask! This is not in my field and I might have missed something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Target > Signing & Capabilities > Team

Select a team and then Xcode will help do the next things.

[image: select a Team here]

Comment: Do I need to do this for both the item under "Target"? Thanks

Comment: Double comment, but thanks for pointing out that I needed to go to the 'Target' menu; there were two items under that menu and I had only selected the team for the first item.

Comment: No, you just need to do this for the target with the same name as your project

Answer (score 5):

I faced this problem after upgrading to XCode 14, and for those who doesn't want to add a development team id, you can do the following:

1- Open Podfile

2- Add the following

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

3- Pod install

4- Run your project

Comment: Do I need to change it ? In my side it still does not work.
```com.apple.product-type.bundle```



 ```Personal development teams, including "Pankaj Pramanik", do not support the Sign in with Apple, Push Notifications, and Associated Domains capabilities.```

Answer (score 0):

Beginners step by step guide to setting the certificates in Xcode right to develop for iOS in Xcode without a paid apple developer account (sanctioned by Apple), follow this link: [Deploying to a Device from Xcode without an Apple Developer Account](https://ionicframework.com/blog/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/)