# react-native - Deploying to an iOS without an Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am running React Native app and struggling with deploying my react native app to iOS devices. I always have the issue:

> Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'

I signed to my app by following this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod) but it fail again.

Comment: There are multiple answers and instructions in the linked question, and those posts are updated occasionally. So please specify precisely which instructions were unsuccessful. In the mean time, I'll vote as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod)

Comment: @Cœur: Thank you for your consideration. Your link is exactly the same as mine, you can click on the "instruction" word to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple.

1. Make sure your Xcode support the iOS version of your phone. In my case, Xcode 9.4 and iOS version is 11.4. If your phone is 11.3, you can choose the version inside `Deployment Target` in Xcode.
2. React native contains 2 projects: main and test. MAKE SURE both of them is signed with develop team and have correct iOS build version.

That solved my problem.