# Use Variable in Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, variables

Hy again, I am still new to objective c and Xcode. I am building a small app and need to use a variable in a Method. I don't know where to put it so I can use it in the Method.

I have a button which starts the whole process but the Method of this button needs a variable which only should be created once (because its a random number) and be saved so the "Button Method" can use it to compare it. Where do I place it so my variable stays the same while my Method can use it?

Thx

```
- (IBAction)guessButton:(id)sender { 
    NSLog(@"Answer = %i", answer); 
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed"); 
    float guess = [[self.guessTextField text] floatValue]; 
    NSLog(@"Guess = %f", guess); 
}
```

Comment: You can use the variable of the class instance which your method belongs to.

Comment: Instead of generalities please show your code.

Comment: Here is my code: - (IBAction)guessButton:(id)sender {
 
    NSLog(@"Answer = %i", answer);
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
   
    float guess = [[self.guessTextField text] floatValue];
    
    NSLog(@"Guess = %f", guess); 
}
This Method should get this varaible-> answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;

Comment: Simply create variable in .h file or create above the viewDidLoad function. You can call variable like self.variableName

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51280883/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in .h file like this....

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface GoogleMapsViewController : UIViewController
@property int answer;//If it's int. Here mention your variable type(If it string @Property NSString * answer;)
@end
```

And call with self.answer

```
- (IBAction)guessButton:(id)sender { 
    NSLog(@"Answer = %i", self.answer); 
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed"); 
    float guess = [[self.guessTextField text] floatValue]; 
    NSLog(@"Guess = %f", guess); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Xcode tells me -> Type name requires a specifier or qualifier

Comment: It all worked out!!! Thank you... the only problem now is that Xcode wants me to set a developer Team. It won't let me compile without, u know why?

Comment: You need to click on left side top file name. This is your project name (Simply go to targets). Her you need to select your developer account in General, see in Signing and select Team

Comment: You see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/requires-a-development-team-select-a-development-team-in-the-project-editor-cod

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to store private variables in implementation class. We can define variable in .m file like this

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSString *stringTodefineAge;
}

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) ModelController *modelController;
@end

@implementation RootViewController
....
```