# Cocoa Swift: Launch At Login not working & throws error in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift4

I am using https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin as it reduces the hassle to implement Launch At Login from Scratch.

I did follow all the instructions in the README as follows -

Made a Podfile & installed with `pod install`

```
platform :osx, '10.12'

target 'myApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'LaunchAtLogin'
end
```

Added a new "Run Script Phase" below "Embed Frameworks" in "Build Phases" with the following:

`./Pods/LaunchAtLogin/LaunchAtLogin/copy-helper.sh`

But I get the error

> cp: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-bcrytpktfvzflmexubmyosnhzksq/Build/Products/Debug/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/LaunchAtLogin.framework/Resources/LaunchAtLoginHelper.app: No such file or directory
>   Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

As you can clearly decode from the error `LaunchAtLoginHelper.app` cannot be found at `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-bcrytpktfvzflmexubmyosnhzksq/Build/Products/Debug/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/LaunchAtLogin.framework/Resources/` that's why the build is failing.

How do I generate that or what should I do to sort this thing out because this makes Launch At Login not work?

I also made a simplest demo for the app to see if it works but it doesn't - https://github.com/deadcoder0904/LaunchAtLoginPod

PS - I have also code signed the application as I did [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217410/6141587) & checked it with `codesign -dvv /Applications/myApp.app` & it returned **Build Time** perfectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<s>Not exactly an answer but found an alternate solution.</s>

<s>I couldn't solve this with CocoaPods but</s> I did make a simple demo with Carthage & it worked.

Here's the link for the interested - https://github.com/deadcoder0904/LaunchAtLoginCart

Edit:

Found the solution thanks to [Ferruccio](https://twitter.com/0xferruccio)

Add a new "Run Script" below "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks" in "Build Phases" with the absolute path to `copy-helper.sh`.

For simplicity, you can just drag & drop `copy-helper.sh`. Drag it inside label **Shell**. Then change **Location** to **Absolute Path**

Also you can try https://github.com/deadcoder0904/LaunchAtLoginPod as a simple working demo.

[image: XCODE DEMO IMAGE]

Comment: This isn't a solution, this is cargo-cult programming. The error didn't go away, Xcode just stopped reporting it.

Comment: Whatever it works for me & my app so Idc if its cargo-cult programming or whatever ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using `Carthage` instead of `CocoaPods`. Currently, there seem to be lots of open CocoaPods' related issues in this project's repository so you might consider trying `Carthage` and follow these steps.

I solved this issue using the following steps:

1. In XCode, under `Build Settings`, under `signing`, make sure `Code Signing Identity` is set to either `Sign to Run Locally` or any other form of actual signing
2. Use [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/416-carthage-tutorial-getting-started) to install Carthage
3. Follow the install and usage of the package, using Carthage, as appears in the README file here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin
4. Delete all of the contents in DerivedData
5. To make sure, also clean the project: (Product -> Clean Build Folder)
6. In your project's folder, execute `carthage build`
7. There should now be a new folder inside your project's root folder named `Carthage`. Inside, there is a `Build` folder. Search for the file `LaunchAtLogin.framework.dSYM` (note the .dSYM extension)
8. In XCode, under `Build Phases`, in `Embed Frameworks` step, drag and drop the `.dSYM` file (see image below)
9. Change the destination to `Products Directory` (see image below)
10. Check the `Code Sign On Copy` checkbox of this framework (see image below)
11. Add another step `New Run Script Phase`, make sure it runs the native shell (`/bin/sh`). Inside, add this line: `exec "${PROJECT_DIR}/Carthage/Build/Mac/LaunchAtLogin.framework/Resources/copy-helper.sh"` (this is the line that appears in the repository) - (see image below)
12. Make sure that the script appears after the embedded framework
13. Build and run

[image: image for steps 8-12]

Comment: above is at odds with https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-macos