# Failed to render and update auto layout status, Failed to launch designables agent because tool was shutting down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I start working on an iOS project and it's using IB and storyboard. I build it after cloning from the repository and it was successful. But the problem is after simply clicking on the storyboard or change something it would not run and throw some errors.
I use Xcode 12.4 and I think maybe it's a version problem.

> Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ReportsViewController (1DJ-2Y-KKP):
> Failed to launch designables agent because tool was shutting down.
> Check the console for a more detailed description and please file a
> bug report at feedbackassistant.apple.com.

What should I do and what it's saying?

Also, I get this red line in the report navigator:

> No account for team "**********". (Add a new account in the Accounts
> preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Failed to render and update auto layout status for ReportsViewController

This error should not prevent you from building/running your application. It is often a Xcode bug, and most of the times you can get rid of it just by opening a `.swift` file and returning to the `storyboard`, undo & redoing last change or cleaning build folder.

> No account for team "**********".

This must be the one stopping you from running your app, to fix it you must sign in with an Apple account. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56774681/8125224

Answer (score 1):

**Open Storyboard editor. Find this below. Change for the newer device to show.Run.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you're building an app to run on an iPhone, it needs to be code signed
go to xcode prefernece  and log in your apple  developer account.
go to sining and capabilities setting
in team section  make sure correct developer team selected
also you need change bundle id for app