# Signing for "DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery" requires a development team

Tags: ios, flutter

Signing for "DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524148/xcode-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios)

Comment: This worked for me https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402#issuecomment-1149585364

Comment: @MustafaBhatkar you are right! It worked for me, too.

Comment: The link shared by @MustafaBhatkar worked for me also.

Answer (score 11):

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
       end
    end
  end
```

check here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111475